String value from JSON response becomes an numeric value in Python pandas dataframe
I am using Python to pull data out of a REST API and store it in a SQL Database. Everything works fine except for one JSON value in the response.
JSON Response
[
    {
        "pbxId": "XXXcxx",
        "site": "XXX Group - Sydney Office",
        "name": "XXXX Service",
        "extension": "622",
        "totalMembers": 3,
        "totalInbound": 1,
        "totalAbandoned": 0,
        "totalAnswered": 1,
        "totalMissed": 0,
        "totalCallsToVM": 0,
        "totalAdvanced": 0,
        "totalRgTime": 36339,
        "totalTalkTime": 25613,
        "totalCalls": 1,
        "avgAbandonedTime": 0,
        "avgRgTime": 36339,
        "avgRingTime": 10726,
        "avgTalkTime": 25613,
        "totalAbandonedTime": 0,
        "totalRingTime": 10726
    }
]

    response2 = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    d =json.loads(response2.text)
    cdr =json_normalize(d)   
    print(cdr)

when I print the response, the "name" value displays correctly.
Then I insert this into SQL DB
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
    df = pd.DataFrame(cdr, columns = ['pbxId','site','name','extension',....'totalRingTime'])
    df.columns = ['pbxId','site','name','extension',.....'totalRingTime']
    #print(df)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    df = df.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df),None)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO eightwave_RingGroupSummary values(?,?,?,?,...,?,?,?,?,?)",row.pbxId,row.site,str(row.name),row.extension,int(row.totalMembers),int(row.totalInbound),....int(row.totalRingTime))
            cursor.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

Here the value of "name" becomes numeric. And it keeps incrementing. For examples when there are two rows in df, name value becomes 0 and 1 etc.
Any help is appreciated.
TIA
I am expecting the value to be the same as returned from API. I tried removing the str() type casting
PS: SQL DB is correct as manually INSERT works as expected
PS: output of the script. See circled values.
enter image description here

WHERE does the value of "name" become numeric?  How is the column declared in your SQL?  The syntax of your execute statement is not correct.  The call must have two parameters: one is your SQL, the other is a single list or tuple containing the values.  Try putting parens around the rest of the parameters after your SQL.

Please read [mre] then edit your question to include enough detail that we can reproduce your problem (code, data, table definitions, etc, etc)

Please don't hide details. If they're sensitive, replace them in your test data, so we can see the test values from begining to end. You should also be doing that to minimise the example; removing data that isn't necessary to demonstrate your problem.

@TimRoberts That gave the same output. I have several other scrips running the same code without any issue. It is just this JSON value is causing.

Use row['name'] rather than row.name to ensure you access a colum rather than a member of the row object https://trinket.io/python3/54d7dfd619 (the latter gives the row's name, which is its index) This would have been infinitely easier to find if you had bothered to make a [mre]

I solved the issue by using row['name'] to access the Dataframe value instead of row.name.
Not sure why it only affected this particular column.

row.name checks the object's members first (such as for object methods, etc) and then the column values if nothing is found. row['name'] only ever checks the column values.
